# Rxjs Distinct operator with key selector in Angular 2 http?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

i my angular 2 service i have this method :

```
  notify(userID: string) {
   return Observable.interval(5000)
      .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
      .switchMap(url => {
         this.datatService.set(url);
         return this.datatService.get();
    })
     .flatMap(response => response.json().slice())
     .distinct(function (x) { return x.id });
   }
```

How can i use the distinct operator with key selector in this cas ?
When i try to do it i have this error : Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.

UPDATE :

The final result i get with this method is :

```
  {
  id:"f3055770-6e66-4936-8e9a-732b53121549"
  message:"Empty Notification for test ......"
  navigationLink:"/api/home"
  seen:false
  sendedOn:"2016-12-02T15:19:44.856Z"
  userId:null
  }
```

I would like to filter the result, so if i already have the notification i dont want to get in again

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how your data structure looks like, but from the example code I guess that you try to map an array to an Observable sequence with this code part:

```js
(...).flatMap(response => response.json().slice())
```

What you would need to do is create a new Observable sequence with `Observable.from` and then use `switchMap` to get it back into the original stream. Then you can use the `distinct` operator as wished. See this code sample:

```js
const str = JSON.stringify([{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 1}]);

Rx.Observable.of(str)
  .map(x => JSON.parse(x)) // replication of your sample code until this line
  .switchMap(x => Rx.Observable.from(x))
  .distinct(x => x.id)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// output:  { id: 1 } 
//          { id: 2 }
```

[Live code on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wofonisiso/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Can't get your exemple works in my case, maybe i'am missing something

Comment: when i try this :

 notify(userID: string) {
        return Observable.interval(5000)
            .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
            .switchMap(url => {
                return Observable.from(this.datatService.get(url));
            })
            .flatMap(response => Observable.from(response.json().slice()))
            .distinct(x => x.id);
    }

i have only ONE object instead of four !

Comment: it helped me a lot , can you please further explain why we need to create an  observable again